# What's the meaning of #:: in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of `x#::xs` in Scala?

for example

```
 case x #:: xs => {
```

In this case x was a Stream but I suppose that the same syntax is valid also for list ecc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [extractor for pattern matching streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream%24@#%3a%3a). This is not valid for Lists. The lists have `::` (note there is no `#` in the list).

The meaning of the `case x #:: xs =>` is that when the pattern is matched, the `x` will contain the head of the stream, and the `xs` will contain the rest of the stream (tail).

Check the [stream documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) for examples on how to define streams.

Comment: is this equivalent to x::xs for List?

Comment: @Donbeo yes, x :: xs in Lists is equivalent to x #:: xs in streams in pattern matching. You can also check [Extractor Objects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html).

Comment: ok. My understanding is that Stream is evaluated only when it is called. Is in this case evaluated the first and the second element of the Stream? (In order to check the pattern matching)

Comment: Only the first (`x`), and first of the tail (`xs`). The rest doesn't need to be evaluated. But note the stream is lazy evaluated, which means its elements are evaluated only once, and then the value is cached.